# How to develop touchscreen driver for windows-10

Tags: windows, driver, touchscreen

I have USB-to-I2c Converter chip FT232-H from FTDI. I am using it to communicate touchscreen with my PC. Touchscreen has GT911-chip.

I have developed working code for receiving touchscreen co-ordinates and It is working as expected. Now I just don't know how to convert my working C code to make HID-driver for touchscreen.